# Magento 2 : Custom Report with Two Table Join issue

Tags: magento2, magento2.2

I am facing issue with a custom report with multiple table join.

I have created a custom collection into `_initSelect` function.

While I am print this query and run manually on a database server its run perfectly and I get data what I want. But it in the normal case it's not working. Also without joining its working fine and I got data in grid.xml

```
protected function _initSelect()
{
    parent::_initSelect();

    $collection = $this->getSelect()->reset(\Zend_Db_Select::COLUMNS)
                 ->columns(['product_id','name']);

    $this->getSelect()->join(
        ['secondTable' => $this->getTable('sales_order')], 
        'main_table.order_id = secondTable.entity_id', 
        ['status','increment_id','customer_email','DISTINCT(entity_id)'] 
       );
}
```

Here the Main table is `sales_order_item`.

Without Join Output of Report

[image]

Adding join in the collection

[image]

here is code of grid.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<update handle="reports_report_grid"/>
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="adminhtml.report.grid">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="id" xsi:type="string">gridTestReport</argument>
            <argument name="dataSource" xsi:type="object">Test\Testmodule\Model\ResourceModel\Testmodule\Collection\Initial</argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
    <referenceBlock name="adminhtml.report.grid.export">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="exportTypes" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="csv" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="urlPath" xsi:type="string">*/*/exportCsv</item>
                </item>
                <item name="excel" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="urlPath" xsi:type="string">*/*/exportExcel</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
    <referenceBlock name="adminhtml.report.grid.columnSet">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="count_totals" xsi:type="string">1</argument>
        </arguments>
        <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column" name="adminhtml.report.grid.columnSet.product_id" as="product_id">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Product Id</argument>
                <argument name="sortable" xsi:type="string">0</argument>
                <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">text</argument>
                <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">product_id</argument>
                <argument name="id" xsi:type="string">product_id</argument>
                <argument name="column_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-name</argument>
                <argument name="header_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-name</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of joining at **_initSelect** in the class ***Test\Testmodule\Model\ResourceModel\Testmodule\Collection\Initial*** , you can try to join fields in **resource collection class**.

Assume your second table is "**sales_order**" and you wish to fetch "**status**","**increment_id**" and "**customer_email**" from **sales_order**.

Please try to update your files as described below.

File : `Test\Testmodule\Model\ResourceModel\Testmodule\Collection.php`

class Test\Testmodule\Model\ResourceModel\Testmodule\Collection extends ........

```
    protected function _joinFields($fromDate = '', $toDate = '')
        {

            $this->getSelect();
            $this->addAttributeToFilter(
                'from_date_field',
                ['from' => $fromDate, 'to' => $toDate, 'datetime' => true]
            )->addAttributeToSelect('*');        

            $this->addOrderInfo();                       
            return $this;
        }   



     /**
     * Add ordered Info
     *     
     * @return $this
     */
    public function addOrderInfo()
    {
        $connection = $this->getConnection();
        $joinConditions = 'order_items.order_id = sales_order.entity_id';
        $this->getSelect()->join(
            ['sales_order' => $this->getTable('sales_order')],
            $joinConditions,
            []
        )->columns([            
            "sales_order.increment_id as ordincrementid",
            "sales_order.status as orderstatus",            
            "sales_order.customer_email as customeremail",
            "sales_order.customer_firstname as firstname",
            "sales_order.customer_lastname as lastname",
            "sales_order.total_paid as totalpaid",
            "sales_order.total_due as totaldue",
            "sales_order.grand_total as grandtotal"]);        
        return $this;
    }  



}
```

File : `Test\Testmodule\Model\ResourceModel\Testmodule\Collection\Initial.php`

```
class Initial extends \Magento\Reports\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Collection
{
    /**
     * Report sub-collection class name
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_reportCollection = \Test\Testmodule\Model\ResourceModel\Testmodule\Collection::class;
}
```

File : `grid.xml`

```
<referenceBlock name="adminhtml.report.grid.columnSet">            
--------------------
    <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column" name="adminhtml.report.grid.columnSet.orderstatus" as="orderstatus">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Order Status</argument>
            <argument name="sortable" xsi:type="string">0</argument>
            <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">text</argument>
            <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">orderstatus</argument>
            <argument name="id" xsi:type="string">orderstatus</argument>
            <argument name="column_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-name</argument>
            <argument name="header_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-name</argument>
         </arguments>
    </block>     
   <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column" name="adminhtml.report.grid.columnSet.ordincrementid" as="ordincrementid">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Order Increment  Id</argument>
                <argument name="sortable" xsi:type="string">0</argument>
                <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">text</argument>
                <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">ordincrementid</argument>
                <argument name="id" xsi:type="string">ordincrementid</argument>
                <argument name="column_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-name</argument>
                <argument name="header_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-name</argument>
            </arguments>
    </block>
    <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column" name="adminhtml.report.grid.columnSet.customeremail" as="customeremail">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Email</argument>
                <argument name="sortable" xsi:type="string">0</argument>
                <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">text</argument>
                <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">customeremail</argument>
                <argument name="id" xsi:type="string">customeremail</argument>
                <argument name="column_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-name</argument>
                <argument name="header_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-name</argument>
            </arguments>
    </block>

--------------------
</referenceBlock>
```

Comment: I have updated code as per your suggestion still not working.

Comment: Could you please confirm the tables names (main table and second joined table). Do you extend Magento's any default report?

Comment: I have sales_order_item as main table and second table as sales_order.
I have created 3-4 custom report but i am facing issue with join collection

Comment: here is a screenshot of both function: https://prnt.sc/luca0n and grid.xml code: https://prnt.sc/lucajo.

Comment: please check my updated answer. I successfully append order table information with sales _order_item using the code for Magento Report ->Products -> Ordered. (ref YOURMAGENTOROOT/vendor/magento/module-reports/Model/ResourceModel/Product/Sold/Collection.php )

Comment: its working fine Thank you. in the previous solution also its work. I got an error of ambiguous of store_id which I found from the log.

Comment: Your Welcome and Thank you for your debugging.